# Why can't I access an enum from an instance of the class where it's defined?

Tags: java, enums

In the example below, if I try to access the enum through an instance of Class1 from Class2, I get the error: "unexpected type":

```
public class Class1 {
    public enum EnumExample {
        ONE;
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    public Class2 {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class1.EnumExample enumEx = class1.EnumExample.ONE;
    }
}
```

I can access it using `Class1.EnumExample.ONE` which led me to believe that I can't access it using an instance because the enum is static, but I can access other static variables through the instance, so there must be more to it than that.

So why does this happen?

---

Also, I know this probably should be another question, but I'm including this here as an aside in case it's an easy answer: Is there some way for me to access the enum from an instance and still maintain the convenience of the enum's auto-completion in an IDE (Netbeans in this case).

I tried to return the enum in a static method from Class1 in hopes of exploiting the fact that I can access static methods from its instances:

```
public static Class<EnumExample> getEnumExample() {
    return EnumExample.class;
}
```

But when I access it on Class2, Netbeans fills the options with methods from `Class`, and not specifically from `EnumExample`.

I could just use `Class1.EnumExample`, but I'm trying to avoid using the class' name in here for convenience and type-safety, because this code will be reused in different places.

Comment: I don't understand your motivation. "convenience"---use an import (or even static import of enum member); "type-safety"---no type safety would be gained.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik My motivation is difficult to explain (and the terminology might have been wrong), so I tried to avoid going into detail into it and decided to narrow down the scope of this question to understanding the reasons why this behavior occurs. I've since made a new question with a detailed description of the problem I'm facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570037/how-to-build-a-hierarchical-structure-of-data-to-aid-in-development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> A nested `enum` type is implicitly static. It is permitted for the
>   declaration of a nested enum type to redundantly specify the static
>   modifier.

Regardless, a type is not a member of an instance. It is (possibly) a member of a type.

As the specification says, a [field access expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11) takes the following form

> **FieldAccess**:
>
> - [`Primary`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Primary)`. Identifier`
> - `super . Identifier`
> - `TypeName . super . Identifier`

We care about the first case, with a `Primary` expression. You have to access the `enum` constant through its type name, through the name of its enclosing type.

You say

> I could just use Class1.EnumExample, but I'm trying to avoid using the class' name in here for convenience and type-safety,

There's not much more type safe than using the type name in source code.

---

A `Class` instance and a type name are two completely different things. The type `java.lang.Class` is a type like any other (`String`, `List`, `ExecutorService`, etc.). It has its fields and methods. If you have a value of type `Class`, you can use it to access those members. With a type name, you can declare variables, you can declare type arguments, create new instances (with `new`), and invoke `static` methods.