# How to build a hierarchical structure of data to aid in development?

Tags: java, enums

I've been facing a design issue that I find hard to even explain, which is probably why google has been of little help to me, so bear with me on this one.

I'm trying to build a hierarchical structure to help with developing an application. The hierarchy consists of the name of a network request, and inside I'd have the parameters needed and the fields that it would return. The goal would be the convenience and error checking of an IDE to code things in the following manner (pseudo-code):

```
Request request = Requests.LOGIN;
Param param1 = request.Parameters.USERNAME;
Param param2 = request.Parameters.PASSWORD;
mapOfParameters.add(param1,"user");
mapOfParameters.add(param2,"pass");
Results results = connect(request, mapOfParameters);
Field field1 = results.getField(request.Fields.SUCCESS);
```

Not only the code completion would help in getting to know exactly which parameters were needed, but this would also have the added benefit of errors being highlighted if I were to copy and paste this code, since changing the request variable would highlight all the elements that don't belong to the new type of request.

My first attempt was to use enums, but I can't seem to have enums embedded in other enums, so I made an attempt of using classes with enums in them. However, I can't access an enum from an instance of its class, so if I were to duplicate the example above to change the value of the `request`, I'd have to add the specific request's class in each line that references that request, so that I could access the enums. Therefore, unlike the first example, the IDE wouldn't spot the mistake in the last line of the example below:

```
Request request = Requests.Logout;
Param param1 = Requests.Logout.Paremeters.USERNAME;
Param param2 = Requests.Logout.Parameters.PASSWORD;
mapOfParameters.add(param1,"user");
mapOfParameters.add(param2,"pass");
Results results = connect(request, mapOfParameters);
Field field1 = results.getField(Requests.Login.Fields.SUCCESS);
```

I've been going back and forth between different approaches and I don't feel satisfied with any. I also feel like I'm attempting to reinvent the wheel. So my question is, is there a design pattern that tackles this specific problem, or are there other techniques/technologies that I should be considering?

Comment: What IDE are you referring to?:)

Comment: @MariusŽilėnas I'm using Netbeans primarily, but if I could get this on another one I'd also be interested to know.